# CIImage and CIFilters on large image

Tags: objective-c, macos, image, opengl, core-image

I have large image (at least I thing that it is large. And I want to apply CIFilters on it. My image size is 3200x2000. But the problem is that when applying filters, my app gets very laggy. I mean filtering is slow for image with that size. If I do the same with smaller images, it works fine. So I thought that it could be problem of how I am implementing it. Am I right?

By the way, my image processing is done like that:

`NSImage -> NSBitmapImageRep -> OpenGL texture -> Draw to screen -> some OpenGL drawing on it -> NSBitmapImageRep -> CIImage -> CIFilter -> CIImage -> NSBitmapImageRep -> OpenGL texture -> Draw to screen`

While applying filters only this:

`NSBitmapImageRep -> CIImage -> CIFilter -> CIImage -> NSBitmapImageRep -> OpenGL texture -> Draw to screen`

part is in action. Can it be reason of slowness?